# Is there a way to use Sequelize with client-side storage like IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, indexeddb

I'm pretty new to Node.js and Sequelize but I've built a couple web apps using Sequelize. I would like to post them publicly for demonstration purposes (not for practical use), and I don't want any database changes that a user makes to be saved permanently, so I'm thinking that I would like to have client-side data storage for the demo, which I understand is what IndexedDB is (though I haven't used it yet). However, it appears I would have to rewrite most of my code in order to have my app set up with IndexedDB. Is there a relatively simple way to keep most of my Sequelize-based code but use client-side storage instead of server-side storage? Or is this not really possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Any easier way will probably be to create a database for each visitor using the `sqlite` dialect with Sequelize. You can then delete the file and destroy the Sequelize instance when a user ends their session.